# PostgreSQL: Use Constant in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I am storing binary data in a Postgres database that needs to be in many rows. In order to not pollute my setup sql files with the same text I was trying to define a constant and then use that constant in INSERT statements. I'm currently trying something like this

```sql
-- my_data.sql

SET my_binary_file = '\x232120433a2f50726f6772616d2046696c...';

INSERT INTO public."MyTable" VALUES (1, :'my_binary_file')
```

And then this is run using `psql -f my_data.sql`

But this just results in

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
```

I've seen many similar things done using psql command line, but none work.

Comment: I'd try `:my_binary_file`.

Comment: I'm not sure that Postgres supports user variables in this way.  You might have to create a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own configuration parameter, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET) :

```
SELECT set_config('myvar.my_binary_file', '\x232120433a2f50726f6772616d2046696c...', false) ;

INSERT INTO public."MyTable" VALUES (1,  current_setting('myvar.my_binary_file')) ;
```

test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=75c6a8e511d54d9dd855653c5d2b053f).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use session variable and access the value in the variable by using the function current_setting() .

Like this:

```
postgres=# create table MyTable(id int, my_binary_file varchar(1000));
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# \! cat my_data.sql
set session my.my_binary_file = '\x232120433a2f50726f6772616d2046696c...';
insert into MyTable values(1,current_setting('my.my_binary_file'));
postgres=#
postgres=# truncate table MyTable;
TRUNCATE TABLE
postgres=# select * from MyTable;
 id | my_binary_file
----+----------------
(0 rows)

postgres=# \i my_data.sql
SET
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from MyTable;
 id |             my_binary_file
----+-----------------------------------------
  1 | \x232120433a2f50726f6772616d2046696c...
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use variables in SQL, you'd need PL/pgSQL for that. You can use a `DO` block.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  my_binary_file bytea = '\x232120433a2f50726f6772616d2046696c';
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO mytable
              VALUES (1,
                      my_binary_file);
END;
$$
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fb184262bc0b89b4719e954f99bf3630)

And a recommendation as a side note: Don't use quoted identifiers such as case sensitive table names. At the end of the day it'll just give you headaches. Table names don't need to be "pretty".

Comment: re: table names. I agree, but unfortunately I found that out way too late as this project started by using SQLALchemy only which shielded me from such observations.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be mixing up `psql` variables with other forms. The psql backslash commands are explicitly NOT supposed to be SQL and won't work if you run your script via a python script etc, but only with psql.

So - having said that, you can easily do this - you just need to quote the value properly. The psql variables are simply cut & paste style macros, so the exact text will be embedded in the query string.

```
\set my_binary_file $$'\x232120433a2f50726f6772616d2046696c...'$$
INSERT INTO "MyTable" VALUES (1, :my_binary_file);
```

Note how we need to double-quote the value for the variable because there is no quoting where it gets embedded. Using PostgreSQL's dollar quoting for this seems easiest. Note also the lack of a semicolon on `\set` - that is not an SQL statement and it all needs to fit on one line.