# Variables or Functions in Postrgres

Tags: postgresql, function, variables

I have the following code that gets the monthly resignation rate of people in a company

```
---2021
Select
       c.id,
       c.name as Company,
------January
round(cast( float8 (CASE

--employeesatendof2021
((Select count(e.id) from employee e
inner join person p on e.person = p.id
where e.company = c.id
    and e.start_date  Between '0001-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-12-31 00:00:00'
    and e.terminated_at is null
    and p.is_support = false)

+
(Select count(e.id) from employee e
inner join person p on e.person = p.id
where e.company = c.id
    and e.start_date is null
    and e.terminated_at is null
    and p.is_support = false))

WHEN 0  THEN null
Else
  --eMPLOYEEsEPARATIONS2021
(Select count(e2.id) from employee e2
inner join person p2 on e2.person = p2.id
where e2.company = c.id
    and e2.terminated_at at time zone  l.timezone Between '2021-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-1-31 24:00:00'
        and p2.is_support = false)::numeric /
 --employeesatendof2021
 ((Select count(e.id) from employee e
inner join person p on e.person = p.id
where e.company = c.id
    and e.start_date  Between '0001-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-12-31 00:00:00'
    and e.terminated_at is null
    and p.is_support = false)

+
(Select count(e.id) from employee e
inner join person p on e.person = p.id
where e.company = c.id
    and e.start_date is null
    and e.terminated_at is null
    and p.is_support = false))* 100
end)as numeric),2) as January_Resignation_Rate,

----February

round(cast( float8 (CASE
--employeesatendof2021
   ((Select count(e.id) from employee e
inner join person p on e.person = p.id
where e.company = c.id
    and e.start_date  Between '0001-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-12-31 00:00:00'
    and e.terminated_at is null
    and p.is_support = false)

+
(Select count(e.id) from employee e
inner join person p on e.person = p.id
where e.company = c.id
    and e.start_date is null
    and e.terminated_at is null
    and p.is_support = false))
--employeeSeaprtions2021
WHEN 0  THEN null
Else
  --eMPLOYEEsEPARATIONS2021
(Select count(e2.id) from employee e2
inner join person p2 on e2.person = p2.id
where e2.company = c.id
    and e2.terminated_at at time zone  l.timezone Between '2021-02-01 00:00:00' and '2021-2-28 24:00:00'
        and p2.is_support = false)::numeric /
 --employeesatendof2021
 ((Select count(e.id) from employee e
inner join person p on e.person = p.id
where e.company = c.id
    and e.start_date  Between '0001-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-12-31 00:00:00'
    and e.terminated_at is null
    and p.is_support = false)

+
(Select count(e.id) from employee e
inner join person p on e.person = p.id
where e.company = c.id
    and e.start_date is null
    and e.terminated_at is null
    and p.is_support = false))* 100
end)as numeric),2) as February_Resignation_Rate,




CASE l.locale
WHEN 'en-AU' THEN 'Australia'
WHEN 'en-SA' THEN 'South Africa'
WHEN 'en-SG' THEN 'Singapore'
WHEN 'en-NZ' THEN 'New Zealand'
WHEN 'en-HK' THEN 'Hongkong'
WHEN 'en-UK' THEN 'United Kingdom'
end as locale

from company c
inner join location l on l.company = c.id and l.parent = 0
where l.locale = 'en-AU'
and c.id = 2
```

It works fine and does what it's supposed to do

But I've been using and hard coding this part of the code alot

```
--employeesatendof2021  
((Select count(e.id) from employee e
inner join person p on e.person = p.id
where e.company = c.id
    and e.start_date  Between '0001-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-12-31 00:00:00'
    and e.terminated_at is null
    and p.is_support = false)

+
(Select count(e.id) from employee e
inner join person p on e.person = p.id
where e.company = c.id
    and e.start_date is null
    and e.terminated_at is null
    and p.is_support = false))
```

And I was wondering if there is a way to save this part of the script in a variable or function that I can use through out the script without hardcoding it?

Comment: You can use dynamic query inside function. If needed then I can provide a sample query where you'll get idea.

Comment: It would help a lot if you can

Comment: Vide the following post to see how its stored in a variable in a script : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70738681/postgresql-use-constant-in-sql-statement/70739100#70739100
This is the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET

Comment: @jemacosta08 you can use the whole query inside a function or a procedure and pass parameter to it and get the result out as a table type..... sound interesting???  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here conditional input is used for retrieving data. If any input parameter value is NULL or empty string then it'll not used for searching option. Prepare a query based on requirement and store it in variable. Then use RETURN QUERY EXECUTE variable_full_query for executing the query and return result. Always keep in mind that out parameter name and data type must be matched with select column name and data type. Use setof records means it returns multiple records.

```
-- Function: public.rpt_member_info(character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying)

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.rpt_member_info(character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rpt_member_info(
    IN p_officeInfoId CHARACTER VARYING,
    IN p_projectInfoId CHARACTER VARYING,
    IN p_memberInfoId CHARACTER VARYING,
    IN p_fromDate CHARACTER VARYING,
    IN p_toDate CHARACTER VARYING,
    OUT member_id BIGINT,
    out office_info_id bigint,
    out project_info_id bigint,
    OUT member_no CHARACTER VARYING,
    OUT member_name CHARACTER VARYING,
    OUT membership_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$

-- declare local variables
DECLARE v_prepareQuery         VARCHAR(21840) DEFAULT '';
    v_officeInfo           VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT '';
    v_projectInfo          VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT '';
    v_memberInfo           VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT '';
    refcur refcursor default 'test';

BEGIN
    
    /**************************History**************************/
    -- Name : rpt_member_info
    -- Created Date (dd/MM/yyyy): 20/01/2022 
    -- Created By : Rahul Biswas
    -- Reason : 
    -- Execute : SELECT * FROM rpt_member_info('101', '1', '1', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31');
    /***********************************************************/

    -- prepare variable data based on given input
    IF(p_officeInfoId != '' AND p_officeInfoId != 'null' AND p_officeInfoId IS NOT NULL)
    THEN
        v_officeInfo = CONCAT(' AND mi.office_info_id = ', p_officeInfoId, CHR(10));
    END IF;

    IF(p_projectInfoId != '' AND p_projectInfoId != 'null' AND p_projectInfoId IS NOT NULL)
    THEN
        v_projectInfo = CONCAT(' AND mi.project_info_id = ', p_projectInfoId, CHR(10));
    END IF;

    IF(p_memberInfoId != '' AND p_memberInfoId != 'null' AND p_memberInfoId IS NOT NULL)
    THEN
        v_memberInfo = CONCAT(' AND mi.id = ', p_memberInfoId, CHR(10));
    END IF;

    -- prepare query
        v_prepareQuery := CONCAT('SELECT mi.id member_id
                                       , mi.office_info_id
                                       , mi.project_info_id
                                       , mi.member_no
                                       , mi.member_name
                                       , mi.membership_date
                                  FROM member_info mi
                                  WHERE 1 = 1', CHR(10)
                                  , v_officeInfo
                                  , v_projectInfo
                                  , v_memberInfo
                                  , 'AND mi.membership_date BETWEEN ', '''', p_fromDate, '''', ' AND ', '''', p_toDate, '''', ';');
 
 RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_prepareQuery;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Execute the function with specific input value

```
SELECT * FROM rpt_member_info('101', '1', '1', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31');
```

Execute the function when a param value is null or empty. This will return all values of a particular column

```
SELECT * FROM rpt_member_info('', 'null', NULL, '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31');
```

Please check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e0f26dfa36b4636f70bd5267dab29979

Also use variable in a query and return result where all parameter value is available and prepare query isn't stored in a variable.

```
-- Function: public.rpt_member_info(character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying)

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.rpt_member_info(character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rpt_member_info(
    IN p_officeInfoId BIGINT,
    IN p_projectInfoId BIGINT,
    IN p_memberInfoId BIGINT,
    IN p_fromDate TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    IN p_toDate TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    OUT member_id BIGINT,
    out office_info_id bigint,
    out project_info_id bigint,
    OUT member_no CHARACTER VARYING,
    OUT member_name CHARACTER VARYING,
    OUT membership_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$

-- declare local variables
DECLARE v_prepareQuery         VARCHAR(21840) DEFAULT '';
    v_officeInfo           VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT '';
    v_projectInfo          VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT '';
    v_memberInfo           VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT '';
    refcur refcursor default 'test';

BEGIN
    
    /**************************History**************************/
    -- Name : rpt_member_info
    -- Created Date (dd/MM/yyyy): 20/01/2022 
    -- Created By : Rahul Biswas
    -- Reason : 
    -- Execute : SELECT * FROM rpt_member_info(101, 1, 1, '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31');
    /***********************************************************/

    -- execute query
        RETURN QUERY SELECT mi.id member_id
                                  , mi.office_info_id
                                  , mi.project_info_id
                                  , mi.member_no
                                  , mi.member_name
                                  , mi.membership_date
                             FROM member_info mi
                             WHERE mi.office_info_id = p_officeInfoId
                                  AND mi.project_info_id = p_projectInfoId
                                  AND mi.id = p_memberInfoId
                                  AND mi.membership_date BETWEEN p_fromDate AND p_toDate;
 
 
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Execute the function

```
SELECT * FROM rpt_member_info(101, 1, 1, '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31');
```

Please check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7c8ed1d02f51f5df4e263cc36a2d50e8